# iOS7 - Map view pin do not appear until screen is touched

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview

In my app, I download a set of point from a web service using json.
Actualizing the app to iOS7, I am experimenting that problem: the locations are downloaded but  pins on the map are not painted until user touchs and "moves" the map. Then they appear and all work as in iOS6.

How can I correct that behavior?

EDIT:
AddAnnotation is called at the end of a method that receive data, parse the json and pass them to  mylocaction object:

```
- (void)plotBarPosition:(NSString *)data_string {
    // Parse the string into JSON
    NSDictionary *json = [(NSDictionary*)[datos_string1 JSONValue]objectForKey:@"features"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [json count]; i++){

      /*
      PARSING EACH POINT
      */

    MyLocation *location =[[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:nameLoc coordinate:coordinate estado:status antenaId:antenaId];

    [_mapView addAnnotation:location];
     }

}
```

I tryed also:

```
[_mapView performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(addAnnotations:) withObject: location waitUntilDone: NO];
```

but in this case, annotations do not appear at all.

Comment: Is the download done on a background thread and is the addAnnotation call done there too?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995245/iphone-mapview-interrupted.

Comment: THANKS @Anna. I tryed it but without lucky. I just update my question, if it could be useful.

Comment: add your annotation objects in an array and assign to -addAnnotaions: `[myMapView addAnnotations:annotationArray];` also from the line [_mapView performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(addAnnotations:) withObject: location waitUntilDone: NO]; the object should be array. not mylocation

Comment: can you please share code snippet that you are using regarding your mapview.

Comment: thanks @RAJA. I tryed adding a NSMUTABLEARRAY but pin still not appear if user does not touche the screen. Problem appear olny in iOS7. Compiling for iOS6, pins appearwithout touch

Comment: Setting focus of map view after adding the pins might work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995245/iphone-mapview-interrupted) and the comment by @RAJA suggest, call `addAnnotation:` or `addAnnotations:` on the *main thread*.  You could do this using GCD or `performSelectorOnMainThread`.

The option with the least changes to your existing code is to call `addAnnotation:` (singular):

```
- (void)plotBarPosition:(NSString *)data_string {
    // Parse the string into JSON
    NSDictionary *json = [(NSDictionary*)[datos_string1 JSONValue]objectForKey:@"features"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [json count]; i++){

        /*
         PARSING EACH POINT
         */

        MyLocation *location =[[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:nameLoc coordinate:coordinate estado:status antenaId:antenaId];

        //[_mapView addAnnotation:location];
        [_mapView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addAnnotation:) 
                                   withObject:location 
                                waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

Alternatively, to use `addAnnotations:` (plural), you first add your annotations to a local array and give them to the map view all together in a *single* call.  Changes below are marked with `>>>`:

```
- (void)plotBarPosition:(NSString *)data_string {
    // Parse the string into JSON
    NSDictionary *json = [(NSDictionary*)[datos_string1 JSONValue]objectForKey:@"features"];

    //>>> initialize array to hold annotations...
    NSMutableArray *annotationsToAdd = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < [json count]; i++){

        /*
         PARSING EACH POINT
         */

        MyLocation *location =[[MyLocation alloc] initWithName:nameLoc coordinate:coordinate estado:status antenaId:antenaId];

        //>>> comment out direct addAnnotation...
        //[_mapView addAnnotation:location];

        //>>> add annotation to local array...
        [annotationsToAdd addObject:location];
    }

    //>>> call addAnnotations: (plural) on main thread...
    [_mapView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addAnnotations:) 
                               withObject:annotationsToAdd 
                            waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Comment: Tx @Anna. The two solutions resolve my problem. Which is more efficient?

Comment: If by efficient you mean good for the UI, then I would use the one that first adds the annotations to a local array and then adds them all in one shot using addAnnotations (plural) -- the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a protocol MKAnnotation - you have to determine you own class for annotation with realizing of this protocol:

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
```

Then you have to init MyAnnotation and add it on map:

```
MyAnnotation *annotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)];
[myMap addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Also try to call

```
[mapView setNeedsDisplay];
or
[mapView setNeedsLayout];
```

after adding annotations