# MKMapView displays annotations points on simulator properly but not on real device iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i am making an iOS app which tells the user surrounded car wash points, when i run on the simulator , it works fine , on the other hand when i run it on real device, map does not display annotations, no delegate function of map is called , i am using iOS 6.1 and x code 5

```
- (void)nextGeocodeRequest
{
    // if we're done, dp whatever you want

    NSMutableDictionary* htc = nil;
    htc=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if ([addressesMArray count] == 0)
    {
        // do whatever you want when we're done (e.g. open maps)
        [spinner stopAnimating];
        [spinner setHidesWhenStopped:YES];
        // NSLog(@"array %@",mutableCoordinatesArray);

        //NSLog(@"array address in geocoded %@",mutableCoordinatesArray);


        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"array count %lu",(unsigned long)addressesMArray.count);


    NSDictionary *dicSingleRecore = [addressesMArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *strTitle=[dicSingleRecore objectForKey:@"s_title"];
    //NSString *strSubTitle=[dicSingleRecore objectForKey:@"s_address"];

    NSString *strArrayAddressSingle=[dicSingleRecore objectForKey:@"s_address"];
    NSString *strCity=[dicSingleRecore objectForKey:@"s_city"];
    NSString *strCountry=[dicSingleRecore objectForKey:@"s_country"];
    NSString *address=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@",strArrayAddressSingle,strCity,strCountry];

    NSLog(@"address to geocoded %@",address);




    [addressesMArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];



    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        if(placemarks.count>0)
        {
            //NSLog(@"Found placemarks for %@",[htc objectForKey:kAddressKey]);
            placemark =  [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            MapPoint *annotation = [[MapPoint alloc]
                                    initWithName:strTitle
                                    address:@""
                                    coordinate:placemark.location.coordinate] ;

            [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

            [htc setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:placemark.location.coordinate.latitude] forKey:@"lat"];
            [htc setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:placemark.location.coordinate.longitude] forKey:@"long"];





        }else {
            NSLog(@"Address not recognized: ");
        }

        [mutableCoordinatesArray addObject:htc];




        [self nextGeocodeRequest];
    }];
    NSLog(@"mutableCoordinatesArray %@ ",mutableCoordinatesArray);
}
```

Comment: Where is your code .. ??

Comment: where i can put my code?i m new in iOS

Comment: Just put you code here .. for code of display mapview and annotation pin.

Comment: sir iPatel, i inserted my code in my question, plz help out

Comment: I'm guessing you're using a 3rd Party sdk for your annotations and it's missing some binaries for Armv7 (simulator uses x86 architecture). what SDK you're using?

Comment: no , i m not using 3rd party sdk, can any one guide me when i show my first annotation on map, how can i come to know about it?

Comment: What do the NSLogs say when running on the device?  Is the `addAnnotation` line actually getting called?  If so, with what coordinates (log them)?  Are you sure mapView is not nil when running on the device?  The problem may not be in this code or it may depend on where this code is called from.

Comment: @anna when i touch my map and heading to the co ordinates(long and lat) array then suddenly my NSlog shows the viewForAnnotations method called and annotations come on the map, but  i want i should directly come to my zoom level like i can see it on simulator, on simulator , i directly come on my first pin selected from my table view and rest of others records of array become annotations and display on map. - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentCentre2,8000,8000);
    
    [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];}

Comment: just it is last point, rest of the app i have completed, just i want user location then i get the address from the user location and then i show all pins on the map, in second controller , i write the city and get all address, populated table view, the record which i select become the user location in this case and rest of others records will be others annotations, here i can't paste my all code, can not write or paste my all code here, restricted from this site, any body give me email then i can sen my code and screen shots, i have done all things, but tiny mistake , plz help out, appreciated

Comment: Sounds like code might be adding annotations from background thread.  Try doing the add call on the main thread.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841225/ios7-map-view-pin-do-not-appear-until-screen-is-touched/21855155#21855155.

Comment: anna plz can u plz guid me how to set different annotation colour for  the selected record from the table and rest of the others should be different, how to set condition for the first annotation and set the colour for the pin, and also i want to show the Title, subtitle, description and image on my callout, right now i m setting Title,subtitle and coordinates for the annotation, in the custom method, i want to add description and image in that callout, plz help out, your above code looks great but i did not check it on real device, but i thin k it will work, many many ..................Thanks